# why does not first Log.e() method works unlike the second Log.e()?

Tags: java, android

I wrote 2 `Log.e` to **control** my code.

But the **first** one does not work(not looking in logcat). **Why**?

```
holder.rowText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if (holder.rowText.isChecked()) {

                   sharedP.remove(sharedP.indexOf(id));
                   holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
                   holder.rowText.setChecked(false);
               } else {

                   sharedP.add(id);
                   Log.e("control1", str.toString());
                   str.append(id);
                   Log.e("control2", str.toString());
                   holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                   holder.rowText.setChecked(true);

               }
```

**Logcat**:

> E/control2: 2
>
> E/control2: 1

Answer (score 0):

Check your **str variable** maybe you make it **empty** in some part your code:
I think str is empty and threfore it does not give you log for the first `Log.e`.

I recommended you that if you to control **sharedP** varaible value change your first 
log as below:

```
   Log.e("control1", sharedP.toString());
```